# Images height too tall

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to setup a section of a screen with 4 images around each other but there is huge white space between them as per image example:

[image: example of problem]

I would like them all right next to each other. Below is the XML I am using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/test1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/test1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am also trying to get them to the top of the screen but that white space is preventing that.

The images you see dont have any white space at all, the edge of the colors are the edge of the image?

Thanks

Comment: Check out Images they may have transparent background with height and width more than real picture inside of it.

Comment: Remove default padding and margin and set them to 0 to remove white space.

Comment: @SJSSoft i dont see any margin or padding in code.

Comment: android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"

or replace -5dip with 0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the `scaleType` to `centerInside` and the `adjustViewBounds` to `true` like this: (adjust view bounds should get rid of the space you don't want.)

```
   <ImageView
        ...
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

@x10sion:For your information,

### Why should i add this

**`android:scaleType="centerInside"`** is going to center the image inside the container, rather than making the edges match exactly. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353973/whats-the-difference-between-imageview-scaletype-center-inside-and-fit-center)

**`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`** this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Comment: Thanks for this! appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

This: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
should be like this instead: `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, or `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, on your four ImageViews.

Comment: Thanks for this but it didnt work. I used @Jens answer which did.