# how to maintain bitmap dimesnion after rotation

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am converting each frame retrieved from the camera into a bitmap and i display it on an ImageView, but i found that the imageView contains a rotated bitmap so i wanted to rotate the bitmap 90 degrees to set it right again using this line

```
matrix.postRotate(90);
```

now the problem is, when used "matrix.postRotate(90);" the width of the bitmap cahnges and gets smaller as shown in image_1 below. and when i used "matrix.postRotate(0);" i got a bitmap of different width as shown in image_2 below.
what i want to do now is, to have the same dimension of the bitmap regardless of the rotation angle applied

please let me know why "matrix.postRotate" chnages the dimesnions of a bitmap and how to solve this issue

**code**:

```
            //required to rotate the bitmap, because it is initially lopsided
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            //matrix.postScale(0.01f, 0.01f);
            matrix.postRotate(0);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

**xml**:
imageView that hosts the bitmap

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity_ivEdges"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**image_1**:
please see the image in the middle

[image]

**image_2**:
please see the image in the middle

[image]

Comment: what scale type you used inside your xml file in ImageView ?

Comment: @Radhey i posted the xml layout of the imageView..please have a look

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY". inside ur ImageView

Comment: for better understanding refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353973/whats-the-difference-between-imageview-scaletype-center-inside-and-fit-center